# Quickly Identifying the inverse of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For matrix B, How can I quickly tell what it's inverse may look like. I know that it has to exist becuase the det isnt 0 and that the inverse will be the same size. However, how can I quickly know the values of the inverse matrix without actually calculating it?

This is from a practice test, the question itself should only take about 5-6 minutes of a 50 minute exam...

[homework problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EF1H.jpg)

Comment: If there was a way to quickly calculate it, it would be present in all textbooks

Comment: The link does not work for me, you can paste the image into the post. There is a quick way only for 2x2 and some special shape matrices, like diagonal or small triangular ones.

Comment: Please don't post links when you can easily type the matter, as here.   Links can break.  In this case, the image is so small I can't read it.

Comment: I managed to view the link. Rectangular matrices have no inverses. For 2x2 there is a quick method. For 3x3 there are only two candidate inverses, and you can try multiplying them by the matrices in a), b) and c) to see if the entries you are getting are from the identity matrix. Some are quickly eliminated.